# Mysql: Order by boolean value mixed into the results

Tags: mysql

Imagine there is a job portal where people can post job offers

Some job offers are sponsored or premium offers that people pay for. These premium offers I want to display randomly in between search results.

Lets say a user searches for
`programmer`

so I do

```
select * 
from jobs 
where description like '%programmer%'
order by created_at
```

is there a way in mysql to add in random job records that have
`is_premium = 1`?

lets say, each 3 results, I want to ignore the search term, and add a random record with `is_premium`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, the actual search results and the sponsored ads are sorted respectively.
Then, room for the sponsored ads needs to be made in the sequence of the actual search results.
Finally, they are put together, and displayed in defined order.

You asked for every third job offer to be a sponsored one:

```
WITH
SearchTerm AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at) AS search_term_order
    , jobs.*
  FROM jobs
  WHERE description LIKE '%programmer%'
),
PremiumAdd AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS premium_order
    , jobs.*
  FROM jobs
  WHERE is_premium = 1
),
FinalOrder AS (
  SELECT
    id
    , description
    , created_at
    , is_premium
    , MOD(search_term_order + 1, 2) + FLOOR((search_term_order + 1) / 2) * 3 - 2 AS position
  --  , MOD(search_term_order + 2, 3) + FLOOR((search_term_order + 2) / 3) * 4 - 3 AS position
  FROM SearchTerm
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id
    , description
    , created_at
    , is_premium
    , premium_order * 3
  --  , premium_order * 4
  FROM PremiumAdd
  ORDER BY position
)
SELECT
  id, description, created_at, is_premium FROM FinalOrder
;
```

The comments show the adjustments for having an ad in every fourth row…

N.B.:

- Ads holding the search term would be listed twice. This could be handled by adjusting the `WHERE` clauses.
- This requires MySQL 8.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: to be completely honest with you, I have never seen a notation like this before... I guess its a mysql 8 thing? whats the name of this notion? what else is cool in mysql 8? and/or what makes this require mysql 8?

Comment: It is possible that some records will be printed twice (when they are both premium and programmer-relative). If it is not safe you must check that the records which are selected by second CTE (PremiumAdd in above code) are absent in the first CTE (SearchTerm) output. And the order of first two CTEs is dependent by those records must be treated as premium or programmer-relative - if premium CTEs must be swapped.

Comment: And I recommend to perform all calculations in first 2 CTEs - in above code it can be, for example, `2 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at)) AS search_term_order` for first CTE and `1 + 6 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC)) AS premium_order` for the second one.

Comment: @Toskan It's called **Common Table Expression** - and AFAIK became available with version 8. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html The same is true for `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: @Akina You are right about potential double listings. But I did mention them under N.B. As for your second remark: In my CTEs, I tend to start with data collection, and do derive/calculate stuff later on. This is sure a matter of style/choice. (However, your suggested calculation doesn't seem to deliver the same result. Unfortunately, I didn't keep the test data - so I can't verify right away.)

Comment: *so I can't verify right away* It's simple enough. `search_term_order` obtain values 2,4,6,8,10,12,... and `premium_order` oblain values 7,13,19,... - so while ordering by mixed array each premium record will posess after each third term record.

Comment: @Akina OK - I read the question as to move an ad into every third slot. (And I tried to get consecutive numbers for the ordering. Your approach is much more elegant/efficient in that respect… How would you do every third slot, though?) ;-)

Comment: o_O Simply alter multiplying coefficient for `premium_order` from 6 to 4...

Comment: @Abecee can you please explain a little bit how you came up with this and how does it work?

Comment: especially `, MOD(search_term_order + 2, 3) + FLOOR((search_term_order + 2) / 3) * 4 - 3 AS position`

Comment: I think you missed in `FinalOrder` `, premium_order * 3 as position` the word position

Comment: @Toskan I just started with two sequences of consecutive numbers (one for the actual search results, another one for the sponsored ads). From here I played with some math functions until I got a new sequence of consecutive numbers, which did mix the original ones as required. But if consecutive numbers are not really needed (because, e.g., they are not displayed - as in your case), Akina's way of setting positions (Jan 11 at 4:33) is a straight-forward alternative.

Comment: @Toskan Do you have an environment, where the duplicated alias is actually required? To the best of my knowledge: In a `UNION` of multiple `SELECT`s, only the column names/aliases of the first one are observed.